# How to show 5 rows instead of default 10 rows in datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

My datatable looks like this:

[image]

Here it is showing default 10 datas in a single page.I need to **show 1 to 5 of 58 entries** so i tried to put **max:5** but it is not working.I need to show only 5 data and the user may use pagination for other data access.

My code for datatable is:

```
var table = $('#firstTable').DataTable({
        "processing" : true,
        "scrollY": 410,
        "scrollX": true,
        order: [ 0, 'asc' ],
        max :5,
        "ajax" : {
            "url" : A_PAGE_CONTEXT_PATH + "/form/api/getAllSelection/all",
            dataSrc : ''
        },
        "columns" : [ {
            "data" : "selectionId"
        }, {
            "data" : "selectionDate"
        }, {
            "data" : "selectedBy"
        }, {
            "data" : "eximPanNo"
        }, {
            "data" : "eximPanName"
        }, {
            "data" : "eximPanAddr"
        }, {
            "data" : "eximPanPhone"
        }, {
            "data" : "selectionType"
        } ]
    });
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a option called `pageLength`. You can set this for show only 5 entries.

```
 var table = $('#firstTable').DataTable({
    pageLength : 5,
    lengthMenu: [[5, 10, 20, -1], [5, 10, 20, 'Todos']]
  })
```

For details see : https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/46346/how-to-show-less-than-10-rows

Answer (score 1):

You need to use option [pageLength](https://datatables.net/reference/option/pageLength), like this:

```
var table = $('#firstTable').DataTable(
{
    "processing": true,
    "scrollY": 410,
    "scrollX": true,
    order: [ 0, 'asc' ],
    //max :5, WRONG OPTION!
    "pageLength": 5,
    "ajax" : {
        "url" : A_PAGE_CONTEXT_PATH + "/form/api/getAllSelection/all",
        dataSrc : ''
    },
    "columns" : [ {
        "data" : "selectionId"
    }, {
        "data" : "selectionDate"
    }, {
        "data" : "selectedBy"
    }, {
        "data" : "eximPanNo"
    }, {
        "data" : "eximPanName"
    }, {
        "data" : "eximPanAddr"
    }, {
        "data" : "eximPanPhone"
    }, {
        "data" : "selectionType"
    } ]
});
```