# showing 5 rows instead of default 10 rows in datatable, when "pageLength" , "lengthMenu" is not suit

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatable

Usually will showing default 10 datas in a single page, but mine is 14 !?
I want to show 1 to 5 of 14 entries so i tried to put max:5 but it is not working.

the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikBIc.png) table still more than 5

```
var select_server_table = $("#select_server_table_example").DataTable({
    processing: true,
    lengthChange: false,
    serverSide: true,
    pageLength : 5,
    lengthMenu: [[5, 10, 20, -1], [5, 10, 20, 'Todos']],
    ajax: {
        url: "http://192.168.03.30:8000/api/ipc/all",   // fake api
        type: "GET",    
        // dataType : 'json',
        contentType : 'application/json', 
        data: function(d) {
            d.search = d.search.value
            console.log(d)
            return JSON.stringify(d)
        },
        headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + getToken,
        },
        dataSrc: function (response) {
            console.log("DATA", response);
            return response.ipcs;
        }
    },

    columns: [
        { data: "device_id", title: "device_id" },
        { data: "name", title: "name" },
        { data: "group", title: "group" },
    ],

    error:  function(response){
        console.log("ERROR",response);
    }
});

select_server_table.draw();
```

I tried the discussion [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54339409/how-to-show-5-rows-instead-of-default-10-rows-in-datatable) , and `<table id="table" class="" data-page-length='15' >` but not apply to mine, pls take a look

Comment: Can you include exactly which version of datatables you are using?   Ideally with a CDN link.   It would also help your question if you could provide some sample data / pre-build HTML table instead of getting data via ajax (as that doesn't appear to be the issue, we can take it as read that the ajax data + table initialisation works).  Ideally create a working snippet that demonstrates the issue (see [mcve]).

Comment: please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I just followed how this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54339409/how-to-show-5-rows-instead-of-default-10-rows-in-datatable),before I posted, but I can do so, no problem

Answer (score 1):

I also use DataTables (v1.13.4) and have set to show 5 entries (out of 178) in every page. The following works for me:

```js
dataTables = $('#select_server_table_example').DataTable({
  paging: true, // Set this default as well
  "pageLength": 5, // Try quotes
  "lengthMenu": [5, 10, 20], // Whetever you want 
  ...
})
```

Comment: Here is the [output](https://imgur.com/a/84F5ZP5) from my perspective, thanks for ur suggestion, but seems not work @Stella Tsich