# showing 10 rows in datatable which default isn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I'm creating the table
[(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyCAj.png) but it's rows is way longer than 10

- the js code creating table

```
var certain_ipc_log_table = $("#certain_ipc_log_table_example").DataTable({
  processing: true,
  lengthChange: true,
  serverSide: true,
  // pageLength: 10,
  // lengthMenu: [ [5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"] ],       // I tried both but not work
  
  ajax: {
      url: "http://192.168.03.30:3000/api/log/files/list", // fake api
      type: "POST",    
      // dataType : 'json',
      contentType : 'application/json', 
      data: function(d) {
          d.search = d.search.value
          console.log(d)
          return JSON.stringify(d)
      },
      headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + getToken,
      },
      dataSrc: function (response) {
          console.log("DATA", response);
          return response.data;
      }
  },

  columns: [
      { data: "file_path", title: "file_path" },
      { data: "filename", title: "filename" },
      { data: "extension", title: "extension" },
      { data: "modified", title: "modified" },
      { data: "size", title: "size" },
  ],


  error:  function(response){
      console.log("ERROR",response);
    }
});

certain_ipc_log_table.draw();
```

I read the [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54339409/how-to-show-5-rows-instead-of-default-10-rows-in-datatable)  so that

I tried `"pageLength": 5` or `pageLength : 5, lengthMenu: [[5, 10, 20, -1], [5, 10, 20, 'Todos']]`
but It just not work, how to fix this case

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
processing: true,
 serverSide: true,
  "lengthMenu": [[ 10, 25, 50, 75, 100,500,10000 ],[ 10, 25, 50, 75, 100,500,'All' ]],
```

Comment: `processing: true,
        lengthChange: true,
        serverSide: true,
        "lengthMenu": [[ 10, 25, 50, 75, 100,500,10000 ],[ 10, 25, 50, 75, 100,500,'All' ]],` works the same

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).